# Does Spring provide a clean way for building menus?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I'm building a menu with Spring and I'm trying to understand if there is a clean way of doing this. By clean way I mean some module that allows the following:

- create a link on a menu entry only if the page shown is not the one to be linked;
- apply some CSS class depending on the condition above.

I've just ran accross the spring:url tag: does it have anything to do with what I'm looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is a complexity of user interface way beyond that offered by Spring MVC. You need something higher-level such as JSF or maybe a javascript framework like jquery-ui.

Of course, you *could* build it yourself using the low-parts provided by Spring MVC, but it's going to be a lot of work.

Comment: A lot of work? In theory I need a page identifier and a class uses the identifier to build the menu correctly. I actually thought it was such a common requirement that should have already been there.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to have a look at [Tiles 2](http://tiles.apache.org/) in combination with SpringMVC. Sample app available on [Spring By Example](http://www.springbyexample.org/examples/), search for *Simple Tiles 2 Spring MVC Webapp*.